# Parsing unicode with keys without double quotes in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert the below  python unicode object  without double quotes to json.

```py
x = {
    version: '2.1.2',
    dipa: '1.2.3.4',
    dipaType: '',
    customerInfo: [{
            name: 'xyz',
            id: 1234,
            account_id: 'abc',
            contract_id: 'abc',
            in_use: true,
            region: 'NA',
            location: 'USA'
        },
        {
            name: 'XYZ',
            id: 9644,
            account_id: 'qwerty5',
            contract_id: 'qscdfgr',
            in_use: true,
            region: 'NA',
            location: 'cambridge'
        }
    ],
    maxAlertCount: 2304,
    onEgress: false,
    scrubCenters: [{
        name: 'TO',
        percentage: 95.01,
        onEgress: false
    }],
    state: 'update',
    updated: '1557950465',
    vectors: [{
            name: 'rate',
            alertNames: ['rate'],
            onEgress: false,
            Alerts: [{
                key: '1.2.3.4',
                source: 'eve',
                eNew: '1557943443',
                dc: 'TOP2',
                bond: 'Border',
                percentage: 95.01,
                gress: 'ingress',
                sourceEpochs: ['1557950408',
                    '1557950411',
                    '1557950414',
                    '1557950417',
                    '1557950420',
                    '1557950423',
                    '1557950426',
                    '1557950429',
                    '1557950432',
                    '1557950435',
                    '1557950438',
                    '1557950441',
                    '1557950444',
                    '1557950447',
                    '1557950450',
                    '1557950453',
                    '1557950456',
                    '1557950459',
                    '1557950462',
                    '1557950465'
                ],
                name: 'rate',
                category: 'rate',
                level: 'alarm',
                data_type: 'value',
                data: 19.99,
                timestamp: 1557950466,
                type: 'alert',
                value: 95.01,
                eUpdated: '1557950465'
            }],
            dcs: ['TO'],
            bonds: ['Bo']
        },
        {
            name: 'udp',
            alertNames: ['udp'],
            onEgress: false,
             Alerts: [{
                key: '1.2.3.4',
                source: 'top',
                eNew: '1557943500',
                dc: 'TO',
                bond: 'Bo',
                percentage: 95.01,
                gress: 'ingress',
                sourceEpochs: ['1557950408',
                    '1557950411',
                    '1557950414',
                    '1557950417',
                    '1557950420',
                    '1557950423',
                    '1557950426',
                    '1557950429',
                    '1557950432',
                    '1557950435',
                    '1557950438',
                    '1557950441',
                    '1557950444',
                    '1557950447',
                    '1557950450',
                    '1557950453',
                    '1557950456',
                    '1557950459',
                    '1557950462',
                    '1557950465'
                ],
                name: 'udp',
                category: 'udp',
                level: 'alert',
                data_type: 'named_values_list',
                data: [{
                    name: 'Dst',
                    value: 25
                }],
                timestamp: 1557950466,
                type: 'alert',
                eUpdated: '1557950465'
            }],
            dcs: ['TO'],
            bonds: ['Bo']
        },
        {
            name: 'tcp',
            alertNames: ['tcp_condition'],
            onEgress: false,
            Alerts: [{
                key: '1.2.3.4',
                source: 'to',
                eNew: '1557950354',
                dc: 'TO',
                bond: 'Bo',
                percentage: 95.01,
                gress: 'ingress',
                sourceEpochs: ['1557950360',
                    '1557950363',
                    '1557950366',
                    '1557950372',
                    '1557950384',
                    '1557950387',
                    '1557950396',
                    '1557950399',
                    '1557950411',
                    '1557950417',
                    '1557950423',
                    '1557950426',
                    '1557950432',
                    '1557950441',
                    '1557950444',
                    '1557950447',
                    '1557950450',
                    '1557950456',
                    '1557950459',
                    '1557950465'
                ],
                name: 'tcp',
                category: 'tcp',
                level: 'alert',
                data_type: 'named',
                data: [{
                    name: 'TCP',
                    value: 25
                }],
                timestamp: 1557950466,
                type: 'alert',
                eUpdated: '1557950465'
            }],
            dcs: ['TO'],
            bonds: ['Bo']
        }
    ],
    timestamps: {
        firstAlerted: '1557943443',
        lastAlerted: '1557950465',
        lastLeaked: null
    }
}
```

I tried using hjson and demjson

```py
import hjson
result = hjson.loads(x)
```

```py
import demjson
result = demjson.loads(x)
```

Actual result :

hjson.scanner.HjsonDecodeError: Extra data: line 156 column 1 - line 620 column 27 (char 4551 - 232056)

demjson.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected text after end of JSON value

expected result:

Json object

Comment: All the Keys need to be surrounded in quotes otherwise no JSON parser will read it since it isn't JSON format. Did this data come from and API or something?

Comment: That format is valid for say JavaScript, but otherwise it isn't.

Comment: yes, the data is returned by a node js script

Comment: @Column01 how to add double quotes around all the keys here

Comment: Well automatically in python it's a nightmare to write a script to fix this. Do you have access to the JS script that output's the json data?

Comment: That's not a Unicode object; it's an (invalid) `dict` literal. Did you mean `x = "{...}"`?

Comment: Also you will need to replace `true` with `True` and `null` with `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `demjson.decode()` function instead. Make sure to convert the input into a long string by wrapping it in double quotes and convert it to one line like I did here.

```py
import demjson
import json

# input JavaScript object
x = "{ version: '2.1.2', dipa: '1.2.3.4', dipaType: '', customerInfo: [{ name: 'xyz', id: 1234, account_id: 'abc', contract_id: 'abc', in_use: true, region: 'NA', location: 'USA' }, { name: 'XYZ', id: 9644, account_id: 'qwerty5', contract_id: 'qscdfgr', in_use: true, region: 'NA', location: 'cambridge' } ], maxAlertCount: 2304, onEgress: false, scrubCenters: [{ name: 'TO', percentage: 95.01, onEgress: false }], state: 'update', updated: '1557950465', vectors: [{ name: 'rate', alertNames: ['rate'], onEgress: false, Alerts: [{ key: '1.2.3.4', source: 'eve', eNew: '1557943443', dc: 'TOP2', bond: 'Border', percentage: 95.01, gress: 'ingress', sourceEpochs: ['1557950408', '1557950411', '1557950414', '1557950417', '1557950420', '1557950423', '1557950426', '1557950429', '1557950432', '1557950435', '1557950438', '1557950441', '1557950444', '1557950447', '1557950450', '1557950453', '1557950456', '1557950459', '1557950462', '1557950465' ], name: 'rate', category: 'rate', level: 'alarm', data_type: 'value', data: 19.99, timestamp: 1557950466, type: 'alert', value: 95.01, eUpdated: '1557950465' }], dcs: ['TO'], bonds: ['Bo'] }, { name: 'udp', alertNames: ['udp'], onEgress: false, Alerts: [{ key: '1.2.3.4', source: 'top', eNew: '1557943500', dc: 'TO', bond: 'Bo', percentage: 95.01, gress: 'ingress', sourceEpochs: ['1557950408', '1557950411', '1557950414', '1557950417', '1557950420', '1557950423', '1557950426', '1557950429', '1557950432', '1557950435', '1557950438', '1557950441', '1557950444', '1557950447', '1557950450', '1557950453', '1557950456', '1557950459', '1557950462', '1557950465' ], name: 'udp', category: 'udp', level: 'alert', data_type: 'named_values_list', data: [{ name: 'Dst', value: 25 }], timestamp: 1557950466, type: 'alert', eUpdated: '1557950465' }], dcs: ['TO'], bonds: ['Bo'] }, { name: 'tcp', alertNames: ['tcp_condition'], onEgress: false, Alerts: [{ key: '1.2.3.4', source: 'to', eNew: '1557950354', dc: 'TO', bond: 'Bo', percentage: 95.01, gress: 'ingress', sourceEpochs: ['1557950360', '1557950363', '1557950366', '1557950372', '1557950384', '1557950387', '1557950396', '1557950399', '1557950411', '1557950417', '1557950423', '1557950426', '1557950432', '1557950441', '1557950444', '1557950447', '1557950450', '1557950456', '1557950459', '1557950465' ], name: 'tcp', category: 'tcp', level: 'alert', data_type: 'named', data: [{ name: 'TCP', value: 25 }], timestamp: 1557950466, type: 'alert', eUpdated: '1557950465' }], dcs: ['TO'], bonds: ['Bo'] } ], timestamps: { firstAlerted: '1557943443', lastAlerted: '1557950465', lastLeaked: null } }"

# decode it into json data
json_data = demjson.decode(x, "utf-8")
# Return the 4 space indent the original had
json_final = json.dumps(json_data, indent=4)
print(json_final)
```

If you have access to the Node JS script (see comments above where we discussed this more) that outputs the data, you can stringyify the JavaScript object before sending it to the API for python.
`var pyJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);` will output the proper json data format

Comment: Here is what the script prints at the end. https://pastebin.com/7fDPLWk8

Comment: demjson.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected text after end of JSON value. I see this error sometimes. What could be the reason?

Comment: Can you post a pastebin link of the data you are trying to decode?